# JavaScript Closures and variable reference

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm reading Cameron's, *HTM5 JavaScript & JQuery*. In his section on JavaScript and closures he gives this example:

```
function f2() 
{ 
   var i = 0; 
   return function() { 
      return ++i; 
   }; 
}
```

When the anonymous function was defined inside function f2 it “closed” over its environment as it existed at that point of time, and kept a copy of that environment. Since the variable i was accessible when the function was declared, it is still available when the function is invoked. **JavaScript has realised that the anonymous function refers to the variable i, and that this function has not been destroyed, and therefore it has not destroyed the i variable it depends on**.

In this bold section where he writes "JavaScript has realised..." does this mean that when JS identifies a dependency between an enclosed variable (i.e. outside the closure) and a closure, that it retains the reference to the variable for later use, whereas if there was no dependency upon the variable it would be destroyed (garbage collected)? So var i below would be destroyed, whereas var i in the closure example above is not?

```
function f2() 
{ 
   var i = 0; 
}
```

Cameron, Dane (2013-10-30). A Software Engineer Learns HTML5, JavaScript and jQuery: A guide to standards-based web applications (p. 74). Cisdal Publishing. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Yes. When it's no longer referenced, it's destroyed by GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is 'yes, that is correct' perhaps a longer example will help?

```
function main() {
    var i = 0;
    var int = setInterval(
        function() {
            console.log(++i);
            if ( i > 9 ) {
                clearInterval(int);
            }
        }, 100);
}
```

As per the example you gave, the variable `i` is referenced from the inner function, and is therefore kept around for as long as that inner function is in use.

In this example, `int` is also kept alive for the same reason, but here we also demonstrate how the GC will clean up when it can. Once `i > 9` the Interval timer is cleared, meaning that there is no longer a reference to the inner function. This then also means that the variables `i` and `int` referenced by that inner function are no-longer referenced, meaning that the GC can destroy them all.